# The eigenvalue of a special $n \times n$ matrix, where the rank is 2.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am given the following question:$$$$
A is a $n \times n$ matrix with the following characteristic:
$$A =\left(\begin{matrix} 
0 & 1& 0& 1& \cdots\\
1 & 0& 1& 0& \cdots\\
0 & 1& 0& 1& \cdots\\
1 & 0& 1& 0& \cdots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots 
 \end{matrix}\right)$$

What is the eigenvalues of A? The answer is $\pm\frac{n}{2}$ which I belive is just an approximation. However, I can't find this approximation. The best I  perceived is the rank of matrix A is 2. So now I know $\lambda = 0$ is repeated $n-2$ times. The exact eigenvalues for $n = 2$ is $\pm1$; $n = 3$ is $\pm \sqrt{2}$, and $n =4$ is $\pm2$ but I can't reach $\pm\frac{n}{2}$ systematically. Please advise.

Comment: Your 'expansion' of $A$ and explicit definition don't seem to match up. In particular, $a_{22}$ should be $1$ since $2 \cdot 2 = 4$ is even.

Comment: Oh sorry, the below definition is my self-interpretation. I will delete it.

Comment: It is not clear what the matrix is.  Is it zero everywhere, except for the two diagonals off the main one, which are all ones? Perhaps you could give the matrix explicitly for $n=2,3,4$.

Comment: @lhf Edited. Is it clearer? The diagonal is 0. The adjacent of 0 is 1, and vice versa.

Comment: @lhf These aren't circulant. In the case $n=3,$ for example, the $3,1$ entry would have to be 1, but it is 0. They are Toeplitz, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $v_e$ be the vector that has $1's$ in the even entries and $0$'s in the odd entries, and $v_o$ the vector that has $1's$ in the odd entries and $0$'s in the even ones.  Each even column of $A$ is $v_o$ and each odd column is $v_e$ (which quickly gives that the rank is two).  A nonzero eigenvector has to be in the image of $A$, so we can write it as $v=av_e+bv_o$.  However, we can compute:

$$Av_e=\lfloor n/2 \rfloor v_o, \qquad Av_o=\lceil n/2 \rceil v_e.$$

Thus, $A$ restricted to the image of $A$, expressed in terms of the basis $v_e,v_o$ is
$$ \pmatrix{0 & \lceil n/2 \rceil \\ \lfloor n/2 \rfloor & 0} $$

and our eigenvalues are the eigenvalues of this matrix, namely the roots of $x^2-\lfloor n/2 \rfloor\lceil n/2 \rceil.$

Answer (score 1):

The cases for even and odd $n$ are somewhat different from one another. In the case $n$ is even, the nonzero eigenvalues are $\pm\frac{n}{2},$ with corresponding eigenvalues $[1,1,\ldots,1]^{T}$ and $[1,-1,1,-1,\ldots,1,-1]^{T},$ as can be seen by computing the product $Ax$ for one of these vectors $x.$ In the case $n=2k+1,$ for some integer $k\geq 1,$ we consider the vectors $x^{+}=\left[1,\sqrt{\frac{k+1}{k}},1,\sqrt{\frac{k+1}{k}},1,\ldots,\sqrt{\frac{k+1}{k}},1\right]^{T},$ and $x^{-}=\left[1,-\sqrt{\frac{k+1}{k}},1,-\sqrt{\frac{k+1}{k}},1,\ldots,-\sqrt{\frac{k+1}{k}},1\right]^{T}.$ Computing, we see that for odd $j$, $(Ax^{\pm})_{j}=\pm\sqrt{k(k+1)},$ and for even $j$, $(Ax^{\pm})_{j}=k+1.$ But in either case, $\left(\pm\sqrt{\frac{k+1}{k}}\right)(\pm\sqrt{k(k+1)})=k+1,$ so we see that $x^{\pm}$ is an eigenvector with corresponding eigenvalue $\pm\sqrt{k(k+1)}.$

Comment: May I know how to find the eigenvectors in the first place?
For example, in the case where $n$ is even, you found $\left[1,1,...,1\right]^{T}$ and $\left[1,-1,1,-1,...\right]^{T}$. This is not obvious for me, especially when $n$ is odd

Comment: I solved $Ax=\lambda x$ for some small $n,$ and guessed the general formula. I've also been at this a while, so I had some guess about how this would go. Looking at the symmetries of $A$ can help to figure out that all of the eigenvectors will be of the form $[a,b,a,b,\ldots]^{T},$ though.